# Php explode function issue

Tags: php, mysql, shoutcast

I have made this code to put in a mysql database the song information from an xml shoutcast like:
artist-album-title

It works but if the album is not there the insertion is wrong, is there a way to if the album is missing just to insert the artist and title.
My code:

```
$artist = $xml->SERVERTITLE;
$title = $xml->SONGTITLE;
$pieces = explode("-", $title);

$pieces[0] = trim($pieces[0]);
$pieces[1] = trim($pieces[1]);
$pieces[2] = trim($pieces[2]);
$sql = "INSERT INTO test_xml (`title`, `album`, `artist`) VALUES ('$pieces[2]', '$pieces[1]', '$pieces[0]') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE time = now(), album = VALUES(album)";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$artist = $xml->SERVERTITLE;
$title = $xml->SONGTITLE;
$pieces = explode("-", $title);

if ( count( $pieces ) < 3 ) {
    $pieces[0] = trim( $pieces[0] );
    $pieces[2] = trim( $pieces[1] );
    $pieces[1] = "";
} else {
    $pieces[0] = trim($pieces[0]);
    $pieces[1] = trim($pieces[1]);
    $pieces[2] = trim($pieces[2]);
}
$sql = "INSERT INTO test_xml (`title`, `album`, `artist`) "
    . "VALUES ('$pieces[2]', '$pieces[1]', '$pieces[0]') "
    . "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE time = now(), album = VALUES(album)";
```

Comment: Thank you Hasse, it works, the more simple the best.

Answer (score 0):

`array_pad` (http://php.net/array_pad) might be what you want:

```
$artist = $xml->SERVERTITLE;
$title = $xml->SONGTITLE;
$pieces = array_pad(explode("-", $title), 3, '');

$pieces[0] = trim($pieces[0]);
$pieces[1] = trim($pieces[1]);
$pieces[2] = trim($pieces[2]);
$sql = "INSERT INTO test_xml (`title`, `album`, `artist`) VALUES ('$pieces[2]', '$pieces[1]', '$pieces[0]') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE time = now(), album = VALUES(album)";
```

The array your string is `explode`d into will be passed to `array_pad` and if it's not the number of items you want (3) items it'll pad the array up to that many.

Comment: The problem is, if there is an album you would get `artist[0], album[1], title[2]`. If there is NO album you will end up with an empty title and the title in album, like `artist[0], title[1], album[2]`!

Comment: Thank you for your time Jeffwa, and to point me about the array_pad, aim always learning.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
    $pieces[$i] = empty(trim($pieces[$i])) ? 'NULL' : "'".trim($pieces[$i])."'";
}
$sql = "INSERT INTO test_xml (`title`, `album`, `artist`) VALUES ($pieces[2], $pieces[1], $pieces[0]) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE time = now(), album = VALUES(album)";
```

instead of

```
$pieces[0] = trim($pieces[0]);
$pieces[1] = trim($pieces[1]);
$pieces[2] = trim($pieces[2]);
$sql = "INSERT INTO test_xml (`title`, `album`, `artist`) VALUES ('$pieces[2]', '$pieces[1]', '$pieces[0]') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE time = now(), album = VALUES(album)";
```

Comment: Thank you mnv, i will try this later, but Hasse reply first.